# Delete a pipeline from Datafactory IDE

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am pretty new to azure datafactory. I have managed to create pipelines and sucessfully deploy them.

However I want now to delete one of them. It seems it is not possible with the default IDE:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the main problem was that I was using the version1 of datafactory

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is very little functionality left to manage DataFactory v1 via UI.

You can use the following PowerShell script to remove the pipeline:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -ResourceGroupName "name" -DataFactoryName "name" -Name "name"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are on ADF v2 , this should not be an issue , Select the pipeline and try to delete that , see the screenshot below
[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using? This is not the default one

Comment: For me this is the default one , with no changes . Now that you mentioned I wanted to know as to how to do you navigate to the UI ? We go to the https://ms-adf.azure.com/datafactories and then select our subscription and data factory name  . Are you also doing the same . I don't see any option to customize the UI on my side .

Comment: Actually, from your website it doesn't detect my datafactory

Comment: Just found the error, I installed v1 instead of v2 datafactory, change the solution and the answer is yours

Comment: Good to know that you have a solution , have fun with ADF v2 :)